# Any idea why protractor tests in html report shows skipped

Tags: angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

After running my protractor tests no failed tests, but "skipped" in displayed on some tests as shown in the following image any idea why this happens
[image: skipped tests]

Comment: Could you post how these tests are defined, your protractor config and the directory structure of the tests? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Jasmine skipped test case if any expect statement is not present in it method by default

```js
//IT statement without expect
    it('should verify Deposit Amount without Expect', function () {


        customerPage.depositMenubtnClick;
        browser.logger.info("------------Deposit Menu Button Clicked -----------------------------------------");

        

        //expect(customerPage.depositMessagetxt).toEqual('Deposit Successful');

        browser.logger.info("------------Exppect : Deposit Message -----------------------------------------");

    });
```

[html report of a test without any expect statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsKg9.png)

Hope this help.....

Answer (score 3):

Protractor it blocks should contains a test. In your case you should include at least one test there.

Eg:

```
expect(element(by.css('.foo')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true, 'Element - foo - is not Visible!');
```

More locators can be found in here: [Protractor API](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api)

This is the reason for the reporter to say skipped unless you have intentionally skipping an it block by using

```
xit
```

But if xit being used the reporter will show the xit count in the report summery.